# Help solving this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find $V(t)$, where $g,k$ are constants.

Thanks!

$\frac{dV}{dt}=g-kV^{2}$.[WHAT I GOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v3Vt.png)

Comment: Here is some help: this is a **separable** equation.

Comment: From the above hint (@Did) we have:
$\frac{dV}{g-kV^{2}}=dt$.

Can you figure the rest out from here?

Comment: @Joseph  No, Sorry that is the part that i got stuck on :(. I tried using U substitution but it didn't work out in the end. My teacher recommended doing partial fractions on the terms to help integrate but i couldn't do it :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dV}{g-kV^{2}}=\int dt$$
For the LHS, factor out a *g* to obtain:

$$\int \frac{dV}{g(1-\frac{kV^{2}}{g})}=\int dt$$

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{k}{g}}V$, then $du=\sqrt{\frac{k}{g}}dV$.

This gives $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{g}}\int \frac{du}{1-u^{2}}=\int dt$$

Are you able to continue from here?

**Note**: $$\int \frac{du}{1-u^2}=\tanh^{-1}{(u)}+c$$

This gives us $$\frac{\tanh^{-1}{(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}}v)}{\sqrt{ab}}=t+c_{1}$$

Solving for *v* we get: $v(t)=\frac{\tanh({\sqrt{ab}t+\sqrt{ab}c_{1}})}{\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}}$.

Comment: @maths do you need more assistance or is this enough for you to continue?

Comment: Sorry i took too long, I have included what I tried to do in the original post (WHAT I GOT). But i think it is wrong :(. Could you please show me how you would have done it?

Comment: sorry i didn't think i linked

Comment: I have finished the rest of the computations, does this help?

Comment: Thank you! Very different from what I have :3

Comment: You are welcome!